# Font Face not working

Tags: html, css, fonts

I want to add font face to my website, but there's something wrong in the code and I don't know what

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ostrich-regular-webfont';
  src: url('https://ostrichsans.googlecode.com/svn/ostrich-regular-webfont.eot');
  src: url('https://ostrichsans.googlecode.com/svn/ostrich-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('https://ostrichsans.googlecode.com/svn/ostrich-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('https://ostrichsans.googlecode.com/svn/ostrich-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('https://ostrichsans.googlecode.com/svn/ostrich-regular-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
       url('https://ostrichsans.googlecode.com/svn/ostrich-regular-webfont.svg#ostrich-regular-webfont') format('svg');
}

    #contentmiddle h1 {
        font-family: 'ostrich-regular-webfont';
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried downloading it and doing the same thing locally?

Answer (score 0):

Ostrich Sans is a font you can get for free in [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/ostrich-sans). Download it, then select the one that you want to use (I guess you want the regular). They also have a [Webfont Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) where you can upload the selected font and it will automatically generate the code you need to use this font in your site, with the font hosted in your own server.

It will be something like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ostrich_sansmedium';
    src: url('ostrich-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('ostrich-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('ostrich-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('ostrich-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('ostrich-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('ostrich-regular-webfont.svg#ostrich_sansmedium') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body {
    font-family: 'ostrich_sansmedium';
}
```

You can get more information on how to use custom fonts in [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)

Comment: Your comment is really helpful, but for some reason it still not works, and I don't know why.

Comment: There may be 2 reasons:
1. Your `#contentmiddle h1` selector is not correct.
2. You are loading the file from your file system, i.e.: file://path/index.html instead of using a web server, doing this won't let you load the fonts from googlecode.com. Could you share your HTML code?

Comment: I didn't understand the second reason, anyway here's the HTML code http://pastebin.com/x3aJUryT

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#contentmiddle h1{
    font: 'ostrich-regular-webfont';
}
```

Use the body tag if you want the font as default for the whole site.

```
body{
    font: 'ostrich-regular-webfont';
}
```